# Как разбить число на массив из цифр?

Tags: javascript

Как разбить число на массив из цифр?

```
const num = 123456
// [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: самый лучший вариант

Comment: `[...''+12345].map(Number)`

Answer (score 5):

```js
let number = 123456;
let array = (""+number).split("").map(Number)
console.log(array);
```

```js
let number = 123456;
let array = [...number.toString()].map(Number);
console.log(array);
```

```js
let number = 123456;
let array = Array.from(number.toString(), Number)
console.log(array);
```

Comment: это string ....

Comment: Задача то не выполнена, нужно получить масив цифр, а получили строк)

Comment: @АрамГаспарян исправил

Answer (score 4):

#### №1. С помощью метода `split()`

```js
const
    num = 123456,
    arr = ('' + num).split('')

console.log(arr.map(Number))
```

#### №2. Копируем с помощью `Object.assign`

```js
const
    num = 123456,
    arr = Object.assign([], '' + num)

console.log(arr.map(Number))
```

#### №3. Одалживаем метод `map` у массивов

```js
const
    num = 123456,
    arr = [].map.call('' + num, l => l)

console.log(arr.map(Number))
```

#### №4. Деструктуризация

```js
const
    num = 123456,
    arr = [...'' + num]

console.log(arr.map(Number))
```

#### №5. Статический метод `Array.from()`

```js
const
    num = 123456,
    arr = Array.from('' + num)

console.log(arr.map(Number))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const num = 123456;
let result = String(num).split('').map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Может  математику?

```js
function numberToArray(x, base) {
  x = Math.abs(x);
  let result = [];
  do {
    result.push(x % base);
    x = Math.floor(x / base);
  } while (x != 0);
  return result.reverse();
}

const num = 123456;
const result = numberToArray(num, 10);
console.log(result);
```